# Unable to view print preview when printing in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to print an envelope.  I can do this on different size envelopes.  So printing is not the problem.

What is the problem is that the print preview (from windows, not the vb.net object) is not showing the preview.  Here is the code I have thus far:

```
Private Sub btn_PrintEnvelope_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_PrintEnvelope.Click
        Dim PageSetup As New PageSettings

        If cb_EnvelopeSize.SelectedIndex <> -1 Then
            Select Case cb_EnvelopeSize.SelectedIndex
                Case 0  '~~ #10 Envlope
                    With PageSetup
                        .Margins.Left = 218
                        .Margins.Right = 253
                        .Margins.Top = 0
                        .Margins.Bottom = 100
                        .Landscape = False
                    End With
                Case 1  '~~ 6x9 Envelope
                    With PageSetup
                        .Margins.Left = 125
                        .Margins.Right = 160
                        .Margins.Top = 0
                        .Margins.Bottom = 200
                        .Landscape = False
                    End With
                Case 2  '~~ A7 Envelope
                    With PageSetup
                        .Margins.Left = 163
                        .Margins.Right = 198
                        .Margins.Top = 5
                        .Margins.Bottom = 415
                        .Landscape = False
                    End With
            End Select

            PrintDoc.DefaultPageSettings = PageSetup
            PrintDoc.DocumentName = "Client Envelope"

            PrintDialog.ShowHelp = True

            PrintDialog.Document = PrintDoc

            If PrintDialog.ShowDialog() = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
                PrintDoc.Print()
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
```

and this is what I get on the preview:

[image: The Print Preview Dialog]

From all the documentation I have read, this should work.  But when I put a break on the code inside the PrintDoc_PrintPage, it does not stop until I select print on window's print preview.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong or what I am I missing?

I've tried to add the print preview dialog control from vb.net, but then I get an old fashioned print preview (which does show the envelope) and then when I select print, I get the above one.  So there is no need for two previews, but I would like that one to work.

I am using Visual Studio 2022 (64-bit) version 17.5.4.

Comment: But this is the same window that is display for every other print job sent no matter what program it comes from.

Answer (score 0):

Use `PrintPreviewDialog`:

```
Using ppvPreview As New PrintPreviewDialog
  ppvPreview.Document = PrintDoc
  ppvPreview.FindForm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized
  If IsNothing(Owner) Then
    ppvPreview.ShowDialog()
  Else
    ppvPreview.ShowDialog(Owner)
  End If
End Using
```

Comment: But to be honest, I have generally found it better to create a PDF and print that out. YMMV

Comment: Maybe if it is a one-time thing.  But I have to print up to 200 envelopes a day, so that would make the print process a very long one.